# Calling one model from another in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model

I have one user model and other is accesscode model. During registration I am using the user model where I have set some validation rules for form data.

On the registration page I have one field which does not belong to the user model i.e. the access code field. I want to validate this field in user model to check 
whether the code entered by user is present in accesscode table or not and also want to check in third model i.e. useraccesscode for that access code.

How I can do this? I am using CakePHP v1.2.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Below example may useful:

```
App::import('Model', 'Student');
$Student = new Student();
$dataArray =  $Student->getDataArray("name like '%".$keword."%'");
```

Comment: bad idea. never ever use App::import and new - ClassRegistry is used for models.

Comment: further bad idea in giving examples that are encouraging SQL injection

Answer (score 1):

```
$validated = $this->User->Accesscode->find('list', array('conditions' => array('Accesscode.name' => $this->data['User']['accesscode'])));

if(count($validated) > 0)
     //means that accesscode supplied in the form matches some accesscode in the database
```

Comment: thanks but I want to implement it on Model do you think this willl work in model

Comment: This solution will work without implementing it on the model.

Comment: +1 This is definitely the most correct 'cakey' way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

```
App::import('Model', 'MyModel');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create instances of other models from within any model/controller using one of these two below methods:

If using Cake 1.2:

```
App::import('model','Attribute');
$attr = new Attribute();
```

If using Cake 1.1:

```
loadModel('Attribute');
$attr = new Attribute();
```